# pg_restore -h localhost VS pg_restore -h 127.0.0.1

Tags: postgresql, server, localhost

I was following a tutorial about downloading a db from a heroku app and pairing it with your local version. This was the process:

To view database in Heroku

```
heroku pg:backups
```

To download

```
heroku pg:backups:capture
```

Public URL

```
heroku pg:backups public-url

curl `heroku pg:backups public-url`> heroku.dump
```

Pair db with local repo.

```
rails db:drop db:create
```

then run postgres restore command

```
pg_restore --verbose --clean --no-acl --no-owner -h localhost -d <YOUR DB NAME> ./heroku.dump
```

Now I have a situation, when I launch a server using localhost, I can access the app and see the added database records. But if I launch a server from 127.0.0.1:3000 , the app is still accessible but no data is retrieved.

I thought that localhost and 127.0.0.1 are not essentially different from each other?

**UPDATE**

So I have realised why this question is confusing people... and I believe I now have the answer to my question:

localhost and 127.0.0.1 are the same but the configuration in my Rails app is defining localhost as the port to listen to. That is why data is showing up when using localhost but not showing up when using 127.0.0.1.

Comment: You run a server on a port, to listen on that port.  Launching a server *from* a port just doesn't make sense.  What did you actually do?

Comment: I did pg_restore --verbose --clean --no-acl --no-owner -h localhost -d <MY DB NAME> ./heroku.dump to add a db with records to local repo. Then, when running rails serve, I am given  "Listening on tcp://127.0.0.1:3000 ,  Listening on tcp://[::1]:3000 " - I can view app through  localhost:3000 and am able to see data... then I can also view app through 127.0.0.1:3000 but I cannot see data.

Comment: @jjanes - I realise my poor use of wording -- but a senior I know has now corrected me and given me an answer-- see in update above. That sound correct?